# reqparse parse a dict

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am new using the library `reqparse` in python. I would like to know how I can somehow parse the `application/json` request sent to my server.

```
[
    {"name": "john", "id": 1 },
    {"name": "simon", "id": 2 }
]
```

I want to do something like:

```
users = parser.parse_args() 
for i in users: 
    print(i["name"])
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this, you need to use quotes:

```
for i in users:
    print(i["name"])

#john
#simon
```